# Adapting PHP to a CSS Accordion

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having trouble setting up the Div structure in my PHP to fit into a checkbox CSS Accordion.  I don't actually know if it is possible

**//Here is my PHP**

```
echo '<div class="accordion"><div class="section">';
    echo '<div class="section-head">';
        echo '<div class="header-lable">'.$field[label].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="rating-letter">'.$image_text.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="editor-content">'.$value.'</div>';
echo '</div></div>';
```

**The accordion I'm trying to get it into is here"**
http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-only-accordion/

```
The DIV structure it requires is this:
<div class="container">
<div class="accordion">
<div>
            <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="ac-1">About</label>
<div class="article ac-small">
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

Any help with formatting this this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Will you setup a jsfiddle.net for this usse?

Comment: ^I don't think a jsfiddle will help with PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure i get what you're trying to do... but you can tweak the php output to this and get pretty close. basically merging both pieces of code

```
echo '<div class="container">';
echo '<div class="accordion"><div class="section-head">';
        echo '<input class="header-label" id="'.$field[label].'" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />';
        echo '<label class="rating-letter" for="'.$field[label].'">'.$image_text.'</label>';
        echo '<div class="editor-content article ac-small">'.$value.'</div>';
echo '</div></div>';
echo '</div>';
```